# Not able to SUM expresssion in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2012

I have a tabular Report like this:

[image]

The values 10,20 n 30 are derived from an expression.
Forex:-

```
=IIF(Fields!End_Date.Value<Fields!As_date.value,0,
IIF(Fields!Tna_avg=0,Nothing,sum(Fileds!Tna_avg.Value),"Data2_Query"))
```

Now i need to total it at last.(total=60)

Add Total is not working..

what i am trying is `=SUM(above expr)` --->> But this throws inner aggregate, out scope error.

I even tried as `=Sum(ReportIntems!Textbox12.Value)` --->> Still throws error.

Please help me how to do sum??

I believe it's a simple calculation, but not able to get it :(

Comment: Its been a while since I've been in SSRS, but in BIDs, cant you add in a calculated field to the datasource you're using for the tablix? If so, could you add a column to the datasource using your expression and simply add and sum that in the tablix?

Comment: i am sorry but i can't add or change the query,

Comment: I thought you could add one within the datasource definition, I wasn't saying modify the query. Like I said, I haven't been in SSRS in quite some time, so I could be wrong about being able to add a calculated column to a datasource. Good luck to ya.

Comment: @Novice_Techie, share your dataset there could be a workaround to achieve this.

Comment: First of all, you have a typo in your expression ( Fileds...).  Second, how is your grouping set up?  Can you include a screenshot of your tablix in VS preview mode?